# Google Play inside Android application

Tags: java, android, google-play

I know we can launch the Google play app this way for a specific product:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.android.example"));
startActivity(intent);
```

But I don't want to leave my app, because after the user can't be redirected back to it.

So, is there a way to open a Google Play product page on Android like on iOS with the SKStoreProductViewController?
Or there is a way by creating our own "Google Play product page" and getting the infos with an official API?

Thanks.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_overview.html in-app billing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is 'No' and I think you have a couple of mixed concepts.

If you're implementing an in-app purchase (as pointed on the link Connor put on the comment) as soon as the user finished the purchase the market closes and your activity resumes (usually receiving a callback about the transaction success).

If you just want the user to go to the Google Play to leave a review or rate your app, you'll have to accept the fact that it will have to leave your app, and the user will return to it if the user wants to.

Comment: the `mixed concepts` comment was in case you're planning the in-app purchase. But I noticed that you reference to iOS stuff. Do not forget some of the core differences of the OSes: Android have the back button and all Android users use the back button all the time. To get back to your app is just one 'back' away. On iOS the user would have to exit to the Launcher, find your app and open it again or open the recent opened apps and find your app in there. On Android the line that separates where one app finished and the next starts is REALLY thin.